# How to set 2nd row as header in ADF (Azure Data Factory) and skip 3rd and 4th line, while importing data CSV

Tags: azure, csv, azure-data-factory

Setting up pipeline to import data from .csv file into SQL table. Here in below sample file want to make 2nd row as header and skip 3rd and 4th line.
[image]

Expected Output in SQL Table should look like below.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I have used a copy data activity and dataflow to achieve the requirement. The following is the sample source file data that I have:

[image]

- Now I have used copy data activity with the above file as source. I have selected skip row count value as 1 for this source. The sink has 1st row as header selected.

[image]

- This would generate the file as shown below:

[image]

- Now using dataflow, select source as this above file. Select another source with same file but skip line count value as 2.

[image]

- This would give data as shown in the below image:

[image]

- Now, use filter on the first source to remove all rows and keep only header. Use union operation on this where you union with the second source. Write this file to sink as csv file. The final data would be as shown below:

[image]

- The following is the entire pipeline JSON for dataflow:

```
{
    "name": "dataflow1",
    "properties": {
        "type": "MappingDataFlow",
        "typeProperties": {
            "sources": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "DelimitedText2",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "copyDataOutputFile"
                },
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "DelimitedText2",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "copyDataOutputFileWithSkip"
                }
            ],
            "sinks": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "DelimitedText3",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "sink1"
                }
            ],
            "transformations": [
                {
                    "name": "filter1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "union1"
                }
            ],
            "scriptLines": [
                "source(output(",
                "          id as string,",
                "          first_name as string,",
                "          date as string",
                "     ),",
                "     allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     ignoreNoFilesFound: false) ~> copyDataOutputFile",
                "source(allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     ignoreNoFilesFound: false,",
                "     skipLines: 2) ~> copyDataOutputFileWithSkip",
                "copyDataOutputFile filter(false()) ~> filter1",
                "filter1, copyDataOutputFileWithSkip union(byName: false)~> union1",
                "union1 sink(allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     partitionFileNames:['op2.csv'],",
                "     umask: 0022,",
                "     preCommands: [],",
                "     postCommands: [],",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true,",
                "     partitionBy('hash', 1)) ~> sink1"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```